# Multiple submit buttons in an HTML form with a MySQL Backend

Tags: html, mysql, forms, submit

I have multiple *submit* buttons in a form. How do I send all the information from the form to a MySQL backend just once? I know how to do it with just one submit button.

Additional information is that I have multiple submits to create a multiple step form and I want to go ahead with the multiple submit solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have multiple forms if creating this without using Javascript

Comment: Why? I just want all the information to be sent to the MySQL backend on the fourth submit button rather than every submit button. I don't get the point of multiple forms.

Comment: Because when you're hitting the first submit button, its submitting the full form, not just the section you've completed, which is why you would need to use multiple forms

Comment: I'm sure there's a way in which I can just accomplish a submit on the fourth submit and not create multiple forms, which would be counter-productive to the goal of me wanting to enter the information only once. I cannot compromise on the form being a multi-step form and am sure there's a way of accomplishing this without adding more forms.